# Sort (categories,Price...), number of products per page not working?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, javascript

I used magento 1.7 and i have a problem.
I am in my catalog that i have many categories list and Sort by Categories , Price ...
The problem when i go to the second page in the catalog it does not work, the url (from myurl to myurl#!___SID=U&p=2) is changed but the list of products does not change.
It does not work also when i click in the sub categories and or sort price.
What is my problem?

Comment: I am sorry but what do you mean saying "change the number of the page in the catalog". Please rephrase your question a bit.

Comment: i go to the second page

Comment: Is your magento installation clear or you have some extensions installed?

Comment: i have some extensions installed. Everything worked well even with extensions and suddenly I have this problem

Comment: do you have an extension or theme installed that modifies the behaviour of the category page? It looks like this isn't standard Magento

Comment: the problem it is without an extension "menu"? How i will resolve this problem ?

Comment: The problem is the # in the URL. This avoids the p parameter to be send to PHP, therefore it is not processed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the # in the URL. This avoids the p parameter to be send to PHP, therefore it is not processed.

Whatever adds the # to the URL needs to be repaired.

Answer (score 0):

In your `\app\etc\local.xml` set

```
<disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules>
```

If your problem disappears than it was caused by some module from **local** pool.

If it did not help, go to `\app\etc\modules` and disable all modules from **community** pool.

If problem disappears enable modules one by one to find out one which brakes catalog list behavior.

Comment: the problem it is without an extension "menu"? How i will resolve this problem ?

Comment: Sorry but I did not get your first sentence. Can you give more details. Did you find the extension that made the problem? If yes what is its full name? Where it is located?